# Is it possible to create custom realm in tomcat without adding jar to lib folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, authentication

I want to make web app with custom authentication. But I have to add Realm into server.xml for this. And this requires me to add jar to tomcat lib folder. Can I keep everything in my war file? How?

Thanx!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deploying a custom realm from a WAR in Tomcat is not possible unfortunately. A custom realm implementation must be accessible in CATALINA_HOME. It is treated as a container artifact, not as an application artifact.

I can only think of these three options :

#### Option 1 : Move to another Web application server

At least **Glassfish** and **JBoss AS** support custom realms deployed from a WAR.

#### Option 2 : Don't use a custom realm

Tomcat 8 now allow for customized credential handling. If may be sufficient for what you need to achieve, instead of going with the custom realmn solution :

> Apache Tomcat 8.0.15 Available
>
> [...]
>
> Add pluggable password derivation support to the Realms via the new
>   CredentialHandler interface.

See http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2014/11/14/apache-tomcat-8015-available

And https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/credentialhandler.html

#### Option 3 : Deal with it

If your solution is already working as intended, you might want to keep it and deal with the deployment issues directly.

Answer (score 2):

Another good option is to use Tomcat's stock `JAASRealm` (`org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm`) to implement a custom JAAS `LoginModule`.  The nice thing about this approach is that the `JAASRealm` can be configured via a classpath sourced `configFile` value so that everything stays bundled in the WAR file.  From https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/realm.html#JAAS_Realm_-_org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm concerning the `configFile` realm attribute:

> The name of a JAAS configuration file to use with this Realm. It will be searched for using ClassLoader#getResource(String) so it is possible for the configuration to be bundled within a web application. If not specified, the default JVM global JAAS configuration will be used.

Here's a simple example of all the parts:

### User.java

```
package com.company.jaas;

import java.security.Principal;

public class User implements Principal {
  private final String username;

  public User(String username) {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getUsername() {
    return username;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return getUsername();
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "User{" + "username=" + username + '}';
  }
}
```

### Role.java

```
package com.company.jaas;

import java.security.Principal;

public class Role implements Principal {
  private final String name;

  public Role(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Role{" + "name=" + name + '}';
  }
}
```

### DemoLoginModule.java

```
package com.company.jaas;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.security.auth.Subject;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;
import javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;
import javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule;

public class DemoLoginModule implements LoginModule {
  private CallbackHandler handler;
  private Subject subject;
  private User user;
  private List<Role> roles;

  @Override
  public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState, Map<String, ?> options) {
    this.handler = callbackHandler;
    this.subject = subject;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    Callback[] callbacks = new Callback[2];
    callbacks[0] = new NameCallback("login");
    callbacks[1] = new PasswordCallback("password", true);

    try {
      handler.handle(callbacks);
      String username = ((NameCallback) callbacks[0]).getName();
      String password = String.valueOf(((PasswordCallback) callbacks[1]).getPassword());

      // todo: perform real validation here (using any desired mechanism)
      if ("admin".equalsIgnoreCase(username) && "password".equals(password)) {
        user = new User(username);
        roles = List.of(new Role("admin"));
        return true;
      }

      throw new FailedLoginException("Authentication failed");
    }
    catch (IOException | UnsupportedCallbackException ex) {
      throw new LoginException(ex.getMessage());
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
    subject.getPrincipals().add(user);
    subject.getPrincipals().addAll(roles);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
    subject.getPrincipals().remove(user);
    subject.getPrincipals().removeAll(roles);
    return true;
  }
}
```

### jaas.config

```
DemoAuth {
  com.company.jaas.DemoLoginModule required ;
};
```

---

All of the above can be packaged up in a jar and included as a library to another application.  That application can use the JAAS powered authentication by using the following tomcat realm configuration:

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

  <security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
  </security-role>

  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>action</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/WEB-INF/jsp/login-error.jsp</form-error-page>       
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>

</web-app>
```

### context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/JaasDemo">
  <Realm appName="DemoAuth" 
    configFile="jaas.config" 
    className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm" 
    userClassNames="com.company.jaas.User"
    roleClassNames="com.company.jaas.Role" /> 
</Context>
```

The `jaas.config` file will be found on the classpath (either local to the web application or in a jar dependency).  Any resource protected by the admin role (i.e. any url with pattern `/admin/*`) will be accessible once authenticated via the admin/password credentials given our simple `DemoLoginModule` implementation.